# Raspberry pi 2 is not booting, Both LEDs are on but not blinking

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I use raspberry pi 2 with ubuntu mate 16.04. Suddenly my raspberry pi is not booting. The monitor can't find any signal (via HDMI). Both the Power and ACT light is on when I start the PI, but ACT light is not flashing/blinking like it normally does. It is just on like no SD card is inserted.

I tried different SD cards, different power cords and different os images (hash checked), but the result is same.

Note: The last time before this situation the pi took more than usual time to boot, and the display was with improper resolution. After that, it is in its present state.

I am starting to think if it is a physical damage and if the SD card reader circuit/slot is damaged. (It did not get any physical hit though) If that is the case, is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extensive [boot problems checklist](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58151) over at the Raspberry Pi Foundation. As per your description the PWR and ACT LEDs are solid red and green, your Pi cannot read from the SD card. As you also checked with different SD cards this indicates a fault either in the SD card reader circuitry or the SoC itself. You may try to visually inspect the SD card slot as well as the area around it for damaged solder points, haircracks, et cetera (don't forget the backside). Other than that you are probably out of luck, I guess.